# The quality of things you stick with

Tags: idioms, adjectives, formality

I was wondering if there is a word in English to describe **the quality of things we stick with**.

For example, if a training is well designed, people will tend to keep using it. Meanwhile, if it's not, they will tend to use it less and less until they give up on it completely.

There is the informal word "stick-to-itiveness" (also spelled "[sticktoitiveness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sticktoitiveness#English)"), of course, but it is used as a noun, as a synonym for determination, a quality that a person has -- meanwhile I'm interested in the quality that an object or product would have.

Comment: In the world of startups and product management, we quite literally use the word "***stickiness***", but you might also want to explore around the word "*retentive*" as well.

Comment: Words such as *endure*, *persevere*, *persist*, *stay*, *survive*, appear relevant to this.

Comment: Devices- I call them "user-friendly".

Answer (score 2):

*"Reliable,"* comes to mind... good for a plan, strategy, or appliance. *"Addictive,"* is another way of looking at it - if the need is compelling. *"Tried and true,"* is what old people say... but it's still useful.

You could also use a word to personify an object (that may project a somewhat unnatural attachment):

"A *loyal*, old car."

"My *faithful* running-shoes."

Comment: Sorry that it took these old fingers nearly 3 months to upvote "tried and true."

Answer (score 0):

You could use *dependable*.

This generally makes one think that it has been both reliable in the past, and you can trust that it will continue to be in the future.